# Saving .go file in neovim with :w causes file to be messed up

Tags: go, neovim

I am pretty new to vim and Go. I am trying to write a simple go file. When I save my file with `:w` the file gets completely messed up. There doesn't seem to be any syntax or formatting errors. It seems like some autocmd is being run, but I don't know what. How would I debug this? Here is my file:

```
package main

import (
  "net/http"

  "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
  router := gin.Default()

  api := router.Group("/api")
  {
    api.GET("/hello", func (ctx *gin.Context) {
      ctx.JSON(200, gin.H{"msg": "world"})
    })
  }

  router.NoRoute(func (ctx *gin.Context) {
    ctx.JSON(http.StatusNotFound, gin.H{})
  })

  router.Run(":8080")
}
```

When I try to save with `:w` in neovim, my file gets messed up. Here is what the file looks like after `:w`:

```
package main

import (
  "net/http"
  api := router.Group("/api")

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"


func main() {
    router := gin.Default()


  "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"

)

func main() {

  router := gin.Default()

  api := router.Group("/api")

  {
      ctx.JSON({
 gi  api.GET(n/hello", fu.c (c{x *gin.Consexg) {"       c}x.JSON(
   .StatusNotFound, gin.H{})})
  }

  router.NoRoute(func (ctx *gin.Conxt) {
    ctxNStaus"github.com/gin-gonic/gin"

NotFound, gin.H{})
  })

  router.Run(":8080")
}
```

I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: It’s not messed up but properly gofmt‘ed: There is a canonical way to format Go code produced by go fmt.

Comment: You probably configured neovim to use a plugin for Go development and that plugin formats Go code on save.  Consult the documentation for the plugin to find out how to disable the plugin feature.

Answer (score 2):

That should mean you are using the [`vim-go` plugin](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go), configured by default to automatically run `:GoFmt` when a Go file is saved.
The file is automatically formatted according to Go conventions.

For example, if you save this file:

```golang
package main

func main() {
fmt.Println("Hello, world!")
}
```

It will be automatically rewritten to the correct form:

```golang
package main

func main() {
  fmt.Println("Hello, world!")
}
```

Additionally, you can configure `vim-go` to use `goimports` instead of `gofmt` by adding the following line in your vim configuration file:

```
let g:go_fmt_command = "goimports"
```

This will not only format your code but also manage your imports (e.g., by inserting any missing imports).

If you find that the automatic formatting is causing issues or slowing down Vim, you can disable this feature by adding the following line to your vim configuration file:

```
let g:go_fmt_autosave = 0
```

After disabling automatic formatting on save, you can still manually format your code by running `:GoFmt` within Vim.